# C++ exception handling and template

Tags: c++, try-catch

I'm new to C++ and have this assignment about exception handling and templates that is giving me problems. I can't figure out why my **catch** isn't working. I'm getting "error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token. Can someone correct this problem and explain why I'm getting this error?

Thanks to all who can guide me.

Edit: Following Tony D's comment, the catch and compiler works, but isn't printing the catch message. The exception class **Error** isn't working as I coded. Any hints on how to fix the class?

Here is my program:

```
// This program demonstrates an overloaded [] operator.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class IntArray
{
    private:
    int *aptr;
    int arraySize;

public:
    IntArray(int);       // Constructor
    IntArray(const IntArray &); // Copy constructor
    ~IntArray();         // Destructor
    int size() const { return arraySize; }
    void subError() const;   // Handles subscripts out of range
    int &operator[](int) const; // Overloaded [] operator
};
class Error
{
public:
int value;
Error(int i)
{
    value=i;
}
};
IntArray::IntArray(int s)
{
    arraySize = s;
    aptr = new int [s];
    for (int count = 0; count < arraySize; count++)
        *(aptr + count) = 0;
}
IntArray::IntArray(const IntArray &obj)
{
    arraySize = obj.arraySize;
    aptr = new int [arraySize];
    for(int count = 0; count < arraySize; count++)
        *(aptr + count) = *(obj.aptr + count);
}
IntArray::~IntArray()
{
    if (arraySize > 0) 
    {
       delete [] aptr;
       arraySize = 0;
       aptr = NULL;
    }
}
void IntArray::subError() const
{
    cout << "ERROR: Subscript out of range.\n";
    exit(0);
}
int &IntArray::operator[](int sub) const
{
    if (sub < 0 || sub >= arraySize)
        throw Error(*aptr);
    return aptr[sub];
}
int main()
{
const int SIZE = 10;  // Array size

// Define an IntArray with 10 elements.
IntArray table(SIZE);
try
{
// Store values in the array.
    for (int x = 0; x  < SIZE; x++)
    {
            table[x] = (x * 2);
    }
// Display the values in the array.
    for (int x = 0; x  < SIZE; x++)
    {
        cout << table[x] << " ";

    }
    cout << endl;
    // Try to print an element out of bounds
    cout << table[-1] << endl;
}
catch(const Error&)
{
    table.subError();
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good that you at least tried to write the `catch` statement, but for the `min` template... doesn't sound like you've even tried anything yet...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't figure out why my catch isn't working.

You `Error` class is not nested inside your `IntArray` class, so change...

```
catch(const IntArray::Error)
```

...to...

```
catch(const Error&)
```

Comment: This works, but what should I change in the Error function so the throw works?

Comment: @TheJons The throw should already "work" for some definition of "work" - it should compile and reach the catch block, but 1) you probably want to `throw Error(sub):` so it records the invalid index and the catching code can display it (you're currently throwing the first number in the array that `aptr` tracks - which seems kind of arbitrary and irrelevant), 2) once you've caught the exception you don't want to `cout << table[-1]` - that will just generate another exception that won't be caught because you're not in a `try` block any more.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hints Tony D. I kept missing the fact that I want to TRY codes and left the table[-1] in the catch block for a long time.